# Changing the style of one table in Rmarkdown with kable

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I'm writing a vignette using knitr and rmarkdown, choosing the rmarkdown::html_vignette style.
Most of my tables are entered as markdown pipe-tables, but I use `kable()` for one.

Generally I like the default style of the tables, but in one particular table (out of several) I would like to suppress the odd-even line shading of the lines.

Is there a simple way to overrule the CSS

```
table thead, table tr.even {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

just for one particular table, generated by `kable`?

Here's a sample file, with the shading on both tables.  I only want it on one:

````
---
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
---

This table should have alternate shading:
```{r output="asis"}
library(knitr)
kable(matrix(1:20, nrow=5))
```

How do I turn it off for just this one?
```{r output="asis"}
kable(matrix(1:20, nrow=5))
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a partial answer to the question.  It's ugly; I hope someone else contributes a better one.

One solution is to define a new style for a particular CSS id or class, then wrap the desired table in `<DIV id="newid"> </DIV>` or `<DIV class="newclass"> </DIV>`.  As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this in the call to `kable()`, so it needs to be put directly into the text.

It appears that the style itself needs to be put into the text as well, in a `<STYLE></STYLE>` block.  Though the header allows you to specify `css`, as far as I can tell that can only replace the existing style file, you can't add to it.

So here is my ugly solution:

````
---
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_vignette
---

This table should have alternate shading:
```{r output="asis"}
library(knitr)
kable(matrix(1:20, nrow=5))
```

Define a style for class "nostripes", then wrap tables in a DIV with 
class "nostripes" to turn it off:


<style>
.nostripes tr.even {background-color: white;}
</style>
<div class="nostripes">
```{r output="asis"}
kable(matrix(1:20, nrow=5))
```
</div>
````